# jqgrid inline edit not working with datepicker column

Tags: jqgrid

I have implemented jqGrid as shown in following link:-
[http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/integrations/inline_edit_controls/index.html](http://jqGrid%20Demo)

By default, when user modifies any value and press enter the row is saved and exit the editing mode. But this doesn't work with the column with datetime picker.

To replicate, Click Order Date column in above demo, select any date and try to press enter. This doesn't work. but works well if you change any other column.

I tried to set focus to the element but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the code of `dataInit`

```js
dataInit: function (element) {
    $(element).datepicker({
        id: 'orderDate_datePicker',
        dateFormat: 'M/d/yy',
        //minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
        showOn: 'focus'
    });
}
```

by adding `onSelect` callback ,which can be about the following

```js
dataInit: function (elem) {
    var rowid = $(elem).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
    $(elem).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        autoSize: true,
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showWeek: true,
        onSelect: function () {
            if (event != null && event.keyCode === 13) {
                $(elem).datepicker("hide");
                $grid.jqGrid("saveRow", rowid);
            } else {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(elem).focus();
                }, 50);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I used your code. What I see now is, when user selects any date, datepicker still remains open. Can we make datepicker hide as soon as user selects the date? and if user press enter, it should save the row.

Comment: @Jay: I'm not sure, which behavior you expect. You want that Datepicker will be seen on focus on the input field of the date? On the other side you want that the user be able to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the field *after* the date is selected. Then one have to set focus on the input field, because <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will be processed by the focused field. Thus Datepicker will be displayed once more. You can insert additional line `setTimeout(function () { $(elem).datepicker("hide"); }, 50);` *directly after* `$(elem).focus();`, but in the case the user will still see Datepicker before hiding

Comment: Ok, so the behavior I am expecting is, datepicker should close as soon as user selects a date. now the row is still in edit mode. Now user hit Enter key to save the row and row gets saved.

Comment: After adding the new changes as you suggested, the datepicker opens and close immediately. and the enter key works. So, its kind of workaround.

Comment: I  would like to have some workaround that would not have any visible disturbance for the user. I have 3 dropdown columns apart from datepicker. I tried to set the focus on one of them, instead of datepicker. But that didn't work.

Comment: @Jay: I would like ... The list can be long, but one can't have too much. You use `datepicker`, which isn't perfect. I can't suggest you more as it provides. You can reduce `onSelect` to call of `$grid.jqGrid("saveRow", rowid);` or to use some variation of the code, which I suggested in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help and time. Your suggestions finally lead me towards something. Thank You.